# SCSS / SASS way to say 'this class and everything inside'

Tags: css, sass

In normal CSS i can say

```
.divclass * {something}
```

and this applies to everything INSIDE divclass, but not divclass itself.

Is there is a shortcut in SASS to do this (Divclass AND everything inside too)?

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to write that is like this:

```
.divclass {
    &, * {
        // styles
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.divclass, .divclass * {
    // styles
}
```